# Sync Looped Timer to System Clock

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a looped timer that I would like to use on a site to time 25 minute lessons with a 5 minute break in between.

The timer ticks over every minute and runs through a total of 30 divs, which gives me the desired result but for one thing.

At the moment, countdown starts from page load. However, I would like for it to start at every hour and half hour by syncing ideally with the server clock (I think I have read that it would be complex and it is easier to sync it with the system clock of the device).

Timing is absolute, as it reflects the school schedule. Lessons begin every hour and half hour, so everyone looking at the page needs to see the same result on the timer regardless of when they load the page.

So that would mean that if the page loaded at ten past the hour, it should show that there are 15 minutes of lesson left. I guess there needs to be some way to pause the countdown after the page loads until the minute ticks over on whatever clock it syncs with, and then spark the countdown from that minute in the cycle.

How would I adapt the JS code to do this?

```
(function ($) {

    $("#lesson-timer div:first").css("display", "block");

    jQuery.fn.timer = function() {
        if(!$(this).children("div:last-child").is(":visible")){
            $(this).children("div:visible")
                .css("display", "none")
                .next("div").css("display", "block");
        }
    else{
        $(this).children("div:visible")
            .css("display", "none")
        .end().children("div:first")    
            .css("display", "block");
    }
} // timer function end

window.setInterval(function() {
    $("#lesson-timer").timer();
}, 60000);

})(jQuery);
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="lesson-timer">
<div class="lesson">
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>25</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>24</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>23</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>22</p>
</div>    
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>21</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>20</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>19</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>18</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>17</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>6</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>15</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>14</p>
</div>    
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>13</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>12</p>
</div>
 <div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>11</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>10</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>09</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>08</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>07</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>06</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>05</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>04</p>
</div>    
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>03</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>02</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Lesson</h2>
<p>01</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="break">    
<div>
<h2>Break</h2>
<p>05</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Break</h2>
<p>04</p>
</div>    
<div>
<h2>Break</h2>
<p>03</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Break</h2>
<p>02</p>
</div>
 <div>
<h2>Break</h2>
<p>01</p>
</div>
</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you care if the page timer is exactly synced with an actual minute?  Isn't the timing all just relative to the viewing of the page itself?  What need does it have to be synchronized to the second with outside agents (other users or servers)?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Sorry if I was not clear in the original post. Timing is absolute, as it reflects the school schedule. Lessons begin every hour and half hour, so everyone looking at the page needs to see the same result on the timer regardless of when they load the page.

Comment: You have an odd "school schedule". Are you sure that most of your visitors are familiar with this particular one?

Comment: Yes. Our school is established and the timetable is known to students and teachers. Each lesson is 25 minutes and there are 5 minute breaks between classes. Example: If my lesson starts at 10:00 and I load the page at 9:50, the lesson timer should show that there is five minutes left on the previous timetable slot & then 5 minutes of break, and countdown from there -- not start counting down from when that user happens to visit the page. Otherwise students and teachers, who are conducting the lessons in real time, will not be seeing the same information about how much time is left in the class

Comment: Students and teachers are not in the same location. We have had some issues with disagreement about exactly when the lesson should start and finish. This is to take the place of a school bell which would announce the lesson start and finish times in the real world. I hope that clarifies it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want everyone to see the same time remaining, then you just have to use an Ajax call to retrieve the time from a central server.  This should be good to within a few seconds (the roundtrip time for an Ajax call).  You can then parse that time into hours, minutes and seconds to initialize a local counter and then show the time remaining in the current 30 minute window based on that shared server time.

For example, if you've use an Ajax call to retrieve a server-based time in a format that the `Date` constructor accepts, you can do this:

```
// parse time and calc how many minutes left in 30 minute class
var serverTime = new Date(serverTimeStr).getTime();
var serverOffset = serverTime - new Date().getTime();

// so to calculate the server time, you get the current localTime
// and add the serverOffset to it

function calcMinutesLeftInLesson() {
    var curServerTime = new Date(new Date().getTime() + serverOffset);
    var minutes = curServerTime.getMinutes();
    var halfHourRemaining = 60 - minutes;
    var lessonRemaining, breakRemaining;

    if (halfHourRemaining > 30) {
        halfHourRemaining -= 30;
    }
    // lessons are only 25 minutes long so subtract last 5 minutes
    lessonRemaining = halfHourRemaining - 5;
    if (lessonRemaining < 0) {
        // in break time now
        breakRemaining = 5 + lessonRemaining;
    } else {
        // in lesson time now
        // lessonRemaining time left in the lesson
    }
}    

var interval = setInterval(calcMinutesLeftInLesson}, 10 * 1000);
```